# Flutter get first word

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get the first word but I can't seem to find a way. I've tried using split like so:

```
Text("${contactList[index].userName!.split(" ")}, ")
```

But the result is an array like so:

```
[aufa, taf]
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What do you exact want?

Comment: Text("${contactList[index].userName!.split(" ")[0]}, ")

Comment: I want to get only "aufa"

Answer (score 1):

according to the results you should write:

```
Text("${contactList[index].userName!.split(" ")[0]}, ")
```

instead of :

```
Text("${contactList[index].userName!.split(" ")}, ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
Text("${contactList[index].userName!.split(" ").elementAt(0)"),
```

Simple Example:

```
void main() {
  String sampleText = "aufa taf";
  var first = sampleText.split(" ").elementAt(0); // aufa 
  var second = sampleText.split(" ").elementAt(1);//taf
  print(first);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Text(
  "${contactList[index].userName!.split(" ")[0]}, ",
),
```